# Running a Stored Procedure in C# Button

Tags: c#, sql

Is there a way when clicked on a button in a C# Windows App, that it can fire off a stored procedure to update data? Im also having issues seeing the SP in my data sources, first time this has ever happened to me. Amy ideas on these things? Should I use an SSIS instead, is that even possible?

Thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertData

 @QuoteNumber as varchar(11), 
 @ItemNumber as varchar(15)
AS
  UPDATE       SF1411
 SET                QuoteNumber = @QuoteNumber, ItemNumber = @ItemNumber, DeleteItem = 'NO'
 WHERE        (QuoteNumber IS NULL)
 RETURN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something similar to this in the event handler for the click event of the button, replacing *ConnectionString*, *quote* and *item* with the appropriate values.

```
using (SqlConnection dataConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            dataConn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConn.CreateCommand())
            {
                dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                dataCommand.CommandText = "InsertData";

                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuoteNumber", quote); 
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNumber", item); 

                dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's something like this...

```
using (SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("InsertData", conn))
{
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuoteNumber ", QuoteNumber ));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ItemNumber ", ItemNumber ));
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

shin's answer looks ok. although i dont think you have to write "new sql parameter".

it should work like this = `cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuoteNumber ", QuoteNumber ));`

Comment: In fact, you should use `AddWithValue`, see the Remarks section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx