# Run stored procedure in C#, pass parameters and capture the output result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, ado.net

This is a simple task that I want to acheive but ASP.NET makes it quite difficult, next to impossible. I followed this question
[Running a Stored Procedure in C# Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124100/running-a-stored-procedure-in-c-button) but found out `ExecuteNonQuery` does not return the output from query.

I tried this other approach but can't seem to pass the paremeters in this way

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myconnectionString);

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.CommandText = "usp_GetCustomer";

myCommand.SelectParameter <-- does not exist
```

Can someone write this simple code, how can I implement it? Basically I am passing a `@username` and `@month` (both character strings) to stored procedure and it returns a number that I want to capture and assign to a label control.

Thank you

The output from my query is this. It runs a complex query, create a temp table and then it runs

```
select @@rowcount
```

and I am capturing that.

Comment: What did your problem have to do with ASP.NET? It was a question of you not understanding ADO.NET. Spend some time reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx.

Comment: for simple thing like this, I have to understand ADO.net, there are books written on ADO.NET :)

Comment: It really wouldn't hurt to read the documentation instead of coding from examples you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` if you actually want data from a result set.
2. Make sure your procedure uses [`set nocount on`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx)
3. Then use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`

   ```
   return (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar(); // value of select @@rowcount
   ```

**Edit:** As for your parameters:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username","jsmith");
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month","January");
```

Comment: this will apply to this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124100/running-a-stored-procedure-in-c-button ?

Comment: Updated to include parameter info.

Comment: so it is working upto this point but now I need to change a parameter value and call ExecuteScalar again. The new parameter name is @Type. Can you help?

Comment: Alternatively, you could leave nocount off, omit the `select @@rowcount` and use the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` for your rowcount.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using linq-to-sql to handle stored procedures. Create a linq-to-sql model, where you add the SP you want to call. This will expose the SP as a function on the generated data context, where the parameters are ordinary C# functions. The returned values will be exposed as a collection of C# objects.

If you have multiple results from the SP things get a bit more complicated, but still quite straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Parameters` collection of the command to set the parameters, and the `ExecuteScalar` to run the query and get the value from the single-row single-column result.

Use `using` blocks to make sure that the connection and command are closed and disposed properly in any situation. Note that you have to provide the connection to the command object:

```
int result;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myconnectionString)) {
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connection)) {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "usp_GetCustomer";
    command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
    command.Parameters.Add("@month", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = month;
    connection.Open();
    result = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
  }
}
```

Comment: Not correct this line: "DbType.VarChar". This must be "SqlDbType.VarChar"

Answer (score 0):

Simple code to get return value from SQL Server

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myconnectionString); 

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(); 
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
myCommand.CommandText = "usp_GetCustomer";

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@USER_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sUserName;   // user name that you pass to the stored procedure
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Month", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iMonth;    //Month that you pass to the stored procedure

// to get return value from the stored procedure
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

myConnection .Open();
myCommand.ExecuteScalar();

// Returnvalue from the stored procedure
int iReturnValue = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);
```

Comment: The value is returned as a result, not a return value. Also, you need to provide the connection to command for that code to work.

Comment: The value is returned as a result, not a return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myconnectionString))
{ 
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(); 
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    myCommand.CommandText = "usp_GetCustomer";     

    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@USER_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sUserName;    // user name that you pass to stored procedure
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Month", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = iMonth;    // Month that you pass to stored procedure
    // to get return value from stored procedure
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;     

    myConnection .Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteScalar();     

    // Returnvalue from stored procedure
    return Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value); 
}
```

Comment: The value is returned as a result, not a return value.